# postgis-jdbc-jtsparser and geotools incompatiblity?

Tags: postgis, geotools, jts

I am trying to use postgis-jdbc-jtsparser with geotools gt-epsg-hsql - the following being taken from my sbt file (same data as relevant maven declarations

```
val postgisJts = "net.postgis" % "postgis-jdbc-jtsparser" % "2.5.0"
val `gt-main` = "org.geotools" % "gt-main" % "24.0"
val `gt-epsg-hsql` = "org.geotools" % "gt-epsg-hsql" % "24.0"
```

On running my tests I get this error:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon.getExteriorRing()Lorg/locationtech/jts/geom/LineString;
```

And looking into it it seems postgis is using jts 1.16.1 or later whereas geotools is down on 1.13.0

Presumably the getExteriorRing got changed at some point.
We are using latest postgres/postgis versions.

Is this a known problem? Is there any simple resolution? We're only using geotools for grid reference conversion (via hsql library)

Comment: Geotools is at 1.17 so you'll need to move back to version 22 or so to get 1.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoTools moved from 1.16 to 1.17 on [July 8th 2020](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/commit/87f2569cdd638d783df6a538f984d37f2641e75b#diff-600376dffeb79835ede4a0b285078036), so you need to make sure you are using a version from before that, which if I'm reading the git history correctly is a 23.x version.

Answer (score 1):

the JTS versions are different, for that you can download the correct version through Geolatte -> Geom 1.7.0(this implements JTS 1.17).
You don´t need to depend only on hibernate-spatial dependencies, download libraries to adapt if hibernate-spatial did not provide.

Comment: thanks, interesting. I'd not come across geolatte-geom. And scala bindings too :-)